# PhpStorm: How to use single quotation mark instead double for auto import?

Tags: phpstorm

I develop with PhpStorm.

For TypeScript project, I like the function "Auto Import" when I typing a module name.

But when I would like to load (for instance) NgbModule, I have the following auto import:

```
import {NgbModule} from "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap";
```

How can I configure PhpStorm to use single quotation bracket instead the double? like this:

```
import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please set **Use** *single* **quotes** *always* in **Preferences | Editor | Code Style | TypeScript | Punctuation**.